# How to share variables across my .rb files?

Tags: ruby, include

I have a few `.rb` files and I want to use the same variables in all of them. Let's say variable `test_variable = "test"` should be accessible from all my `.rb` files. How can I achieve that?

I created `settings.rb` file with `test_variable = "test"` then used `require 'settings'` in another `.rb` file, but it didn't work. I would like to use `require` not `load`.

I tried to make the variable global by prefixing the variable name with `$`, but I am still getting `undefined local variable or method 'test_variable' for main:Object (NameError)`.

Comment: Using below solution and still hoping there is a `simpler` way ... :-)

Comment: All you need to do is add the $ to the beginning of the variable name to use it from a required file.  It looks like you should change the require code from require 'settings' to require './settings.rb' so that ruby sees and loads your file correctly.  Without the file path and extension, it's looking for a gem called 'settings'.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. Constants (which include modules and classes) are added to the shared global environment:

   ```
   phrogz$ cat constants1.rb 
   TEST_VARIABLE = "test"

   phrogz$ cat constants2.rb 
   require_relative 'constants1'
   p TEST_VARIABLE

   phrogz$ ruby constants2.rb 
   "test"
   ```
2. Instance variables declared in main are all part of the same `main`:

   ```
   phrogz$ cat instance1.rb 
   @test_variable = "test"

   phrogz$ cat instance2.rb 
   require_relative 'instance1'
   p @test_variable

   phrogz$ ruby instance2.rb 
   "test"
   ```
3. Global variables are also all part of the same environment (tested in 1.8.6, 1.8.7, and 1.9.2):

   ```
   phrogz$ cat global1.rb 
   $test_variable = "test"

   phrogz$ cat global2.rb 
   require_relative 'global1'
   p $test_variable, RUBY_DESCRIPTION

   phrogz$ ruby global2.rb 
   "test"
   "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]"
   ```

Comment: I knew there would be something simpler...What do you mean by `variables declared in main are all part of the same main`

Comment: @Radek Instance variables (e.g. `@foo`) are always associated with a particular object. When you write `@foo = 42` at the 'top' of a file, not in any method or module or class, that object is `main`.

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong when I was trying your solution even before posting my question :-( Works smoothly. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Ruby will *never* share local variables between files. You can wrap them in a Module though:

```
module SharedVaribles
  @test_var="Hello, World"

  def self.test_var
    return @test_var
  end

  def self.test_var=(val)
    @test_val=val;
  end
end
```

Put that in `settings.rb`, `require` it into all your files, and use `SharedVaribles.test_var` and `SharedVaribles.test_var=` to access the variable. Remember, Ruby's `require` is nothing like C's `#include`, it is much more complex. It executes the file, then imports all constants, modules, and classes to the `require`er.

Comment: Do I need all the lines of code for one variable to be shared? What I need to add if I want to share one more? I am lost in your code :-) Thank you.

Comment: Radek: All this does is create, in C++y terms, is create a static variable for the Module `SharedVaribles`. It provides a static method `test_var` that returns the value of test_var. `test_var=` sets the value. Make scene?

Comment: Yes, now I do understand. Any other, simpler way in ruby?

Comment: No. Ruby is _very_ strict about scope and variables. Only these 'encapsulated' variables can be used in a different file. `require` is also quite an odd beast--sometimes the simplicity of `#include` can be heaven after working with `require`.

Comment: No. Ruby does have an `include` keyword, but it has nothing to do with files. I meant when going back to good old C++ and C. If your really dealing with large amounts of shared data, there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: I cannot believe that ruby doesn't have elegant solution for that ... :-(

Comment: It does have an elegant solution - http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

Answer (score 2):

```
module Foo
  attr_accessor :test_var
  def initialize
    @test_var = "hello world"
  end
end
```

Create the module with your variable or variables in your config file and then include the module in whatever class you intend to use.

```
require_relative 'foomod.rb'
class Bar
  include Foo
end

foobar = Bar.new
foobar.test_var = "goodbye"
puts foobar.test_var
```

Each instance of the class will initialize with whatever value you would like.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to wrap these variables in a `module`.

Simply adding them to `another_file.rb` and using `require_relative 'another_file'` (if it's in the same directory) or `require 'path/to/another_file'` should be sufficient to share those variables across files.