# Shared class instance variable in one line of code

Tags: ruby

I would like to have a system something like: A hieararchy of `Widget`s, each `Widget` containing a class instance variable `@painter`. Therefore each instance of `Widget` will know how to paint itself, but this behaviour can be replaced at runtime.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
class MyButton < Widget

  @painter = DefaultPainter.new

  def set_painter(new_painter)
    self.class.instance_variable_set(:painter, new_painter)
  end

  def get_painter()
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:painter)
  end

end
```

Is it possible (using probably metaprogramming) to shrink this verbose code something down to:

```
class Widget

  shared_attr :painter

end
```

Probably best way is to use define_method in the Widget.inherit override. It could set up the methods as well as the @painter for each class. But I'm not sure this way is the best to do it. For instance, if I create `Button < Widget` and `SpecialButton < Button` I would like `SpecialButton` to pick up the `@painter` class instance variable.

Also, what if I wanted to have `shared_attr`s in other classes. Maybe I could write a `HasSharedVariables` module. And every class that needs shared variables could extend this module. I would like to know the best way to do this, if it is possible.

Comment: What is the purpose of a "shared variable"? Perhaps what you want are globals or constants? You probably should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334684/how-to-share-variables-across-my-rb-files)

Comment: Bad terminology, I meant one variable for each instance of a class in the class hierarchy.

I could use `@@variable` but this is basically like global variables in disguise.

What I need is one variable for the class and each of its descendants (direct or indirect).

Comment: Your idea still comes across as convoluted.  Variable implies state can change.  What is it that will change that you need "variable" for?  Just because Ruby allows metaprogramming, doesn't mean you need to do it. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?  Did you even try to whiteboard it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share code between classes, and this can't be easily done through class inheritance, perhaps a module is what you need.

```
module Paint
  def paint 
    puts "hooray I paint #{self.foo if defined?(self.foo)}"
  end
end

class Widget
  include Paint

  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize
    @foo = 'foo'
  end

  def scribble
    puts "I scribble some #{foo}" 
  end
end

w = Widget.new
w.paint
hooray I paint foo

w.scribble
I scribble some foo
w.foo='splat'
w.paint
hooray I paint splat
```